# Preciso abrir uma conexão com o MySQL para cada consulta em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query, mysqli

Preciso pegar diversas variáveis baseadas no meu banco para montar um dashboard completo. Por exemplo, preciso do número de linhas, do valor médio de um determinado campo e desse mesmo valor médio só que por UF.

A estratégia que tem funcionado comigo é a de pedir o acesso por meio da função `msqli_connect()` e logo depois da solicitação atendida eu fecho com `msqli_close()`. Com isso estou conseguindo só uma ação, ou seja, só a média, ou só a lista de todos os usuários, ou só a soma. Não consegui, por exemplo, conseguir a média e a soma dentro de uma mesma solicitação. É assim mesmo? como posso pedir mais dados em uma mesma solicitação?

O código que venho usando é:

```
// Para conseguir a média
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT AVG(q1) AS avg FROM nome_da_tabela";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row["avg"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }


    mysqli_close($conn);

    // agora para conseguir a soma: 

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT SUM(q1) AS soma FROM nome_da_tabela";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row["soma"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }


    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Não, de preferência não deve fazer isto, em PHP fica até fácil controlar isso porque em quase 100% do casos está só rodando um *script* efêmero, então o limite é basicamente a duração dele, pode ter alguma exceção, mas quase sempre isto é o adequado.

Não é o fim do mundo fazer diferente, se fizer certo, o que complica mais, mas não tem vantagem, inclusive se isso fosse bom nem precisaria exigir abrir e fechar, toda consulta abriria e fecharia a conexão por conta própria. O caso mostrado na pergunta claramente é errado, mesmo que funcione.

Por outro lado a pergunta tem uma outra questão importante que é o abuso de consultas quando só uma resolve. Esta sim causa bastante problema porque entra em contato com o servidor duas vezes e tem processamento quase repetido para fazer a mesma coisa. Este é um caso que não só deveria ter apenas uma conexão como uma só consulta. Ela pede duas coisas na mesma tabela sob as mesmas condições, então faz tudo de uma vez:

```
SELECT AVG(q1) AS avg, SUM(q1) AS soma FROM nome_da_tabela
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/TwoColumns.sql).

Aí pega os dois campos retornados no mesmo processamento. Este código todo pode ser reduzindo para pouco mais de meia dúzia de linhas, o que fica bem mais simples.

Answer (score -1):

Oi, Pedro, tudo bem?

Você pode criar um arquivo para conter a conexão com o MySQL e incorporar ele dentro deste. Desta forma, a conexão com o banco de dados já vai estar aberta e você poderá fazer suas consultas. Finalize com o mysqli_close($conn) apenas quando já tiver concluído todas as consultas.

Ex:

```
Arquivo: connection.php
.
$servername = "";
$username= "";
$password = "";
$dbname= "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Com isso, você pode fazer um include desse arquivo em qualquer página e fazer as consultas, com uma única conexão. ;)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Pessoalmente acho errado abrir conexões sem necessidade, colocar um header com msqli_connect para abrir conexões deliberadamente é o mesmo que consumir algo até quando não precisa, nem toda página vai ter queries para serem executadas, logo manter uma conexão aberta seria consumir mais do servidor de banco. Inclusive tive um problema semelhante, sempre ultrapassava de 150 conexões no banco, o que fazia ou o banco ficar lento ou cair, quando mudei a abordagem, só conectar se for executar uma query ou mais, caiu o numero de conexões para entre 1 e 15 por minuto, e o banco nunca mais caiu.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, entendi seu ponto de vista. Mas a ideia não é chamar a conexão em todas as páginas e sim em todas as quais farão de fato as requisições. Basicamente estou apenas separando o arquivo de conexão e chamando quando necessário. Já desenvolvi e acompanhei diversos projetos que usam dessa forma e nunca vi problemas com conexões em excesso, até porque ela sempre é encerrada logo após a consulta. Talvez essa não seja realmente a melhor forma de usar, mas comigo sempre deu certo. rs

Comment: Ainda sim isto ai não tem controle, teria mais sentido colocar a conexão em static numa hipotética função chamada `function query($query) { static $conn; if (!$conn) { $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, ....); } return mysqli_query($query);  }`, pq ai sim teria maior garantia de conectar só quando realmente uma query for usada. Eu já debati muito este assunto aqui no site e no chat do site, porque a maioria das pessoas não entendem os gargalos que podem sofrer com banco de dados e geralmente não sabem o que estão fazendo.

Comment: @ClebertFigueiredo sem entrar na discussão se está certo, mas pegando no ponto "eu já participei de projetos que fazem assim" é um fato recorrente na nossa indústria. Quase ninguém sabe fazer direito, quase todo mundo "aprende" reproduzindo o que outra pessoa faz, que aprendeu do mesmo jeito e em geral pegam sempre alguém que não sabia o que estava fazendo, portanto todo mundo aprende errado e acha que está fazendo certo, e chegamos no estado lastimável atual onde quase tudo é inseguro, lento e cheio de outras falhas, e as pessoas nem percebem o quanto estão fazendo algo ruim, porque é vicioso

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, realmente parece uma forma mais aplicada de se utilizar. Obrigado pela explicação e por me ensinar algo novo. rs

Comment: @Maniero, isso é verdade. Acaba que as pessoas utilizam algo que deu certo e simplesmente por isso param ali e levam pro resto da vida.

Comment: Dá pra fazer de variaveis, maneiras, essa ai é só um exemplo ;)

Comment: A minha dúvida também ia um pouco nessa linha. Eu tentei fazer várias demandas com uma conexão só, colocando, por exemplo $sql, depois $sql2, $result, depois $result2, e só depois fechando a conexão. Mas por algum motivo isso não funciona. Só quando eu fecho a conexão e abro uma nova.  Posso fazer várias solicitações dentro de uma mesma conexão?